# What difference will static methods in a JAX-RS class make?

Tags: java, static, jax-rs

I've just read some code in a JAX-RS class where a @Path annotated method is static - this is a new one to me. It compiles (doesn't make use of any instance variables) and I believe, for a single user at least, behaves as expected.

Will it make any difference? Are there multi-threading concerns or performance limitations being imposed by it?